# How to quickly find a set of solutions that meet the requirements

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

**Note:** The following questions are from the 21th question of the [2010 Chinese Graduate Mathematical Entrance Examination](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/22edbe503086bceb19e8b8f67c1cfad6195fe9ff.html) (first set):

It is known that the canonical form of the quadratic form $f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\right)=x^{T} A x $ under the orthogonal transformation $x=Qy$ is $ y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2}$, and the third column of `Q` is $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^{T}$.Now I need to find the matrices `A` and `Q`.

I use the following code to calculate this problem, hoping to find a set of solutions that meet the requirements. But the following code runs all the time:

```
Q = {{x1, x2, Sqrt[2]/2}, {x3, x4, 0}, {x5, x6, Sqrt[2]/2}}; 
A = Array[x, {3, 3}]; 
FindInstance[
 Thread[Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
   Join[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, Flatten[A]], Reals]
```

How can I improve this code to quickly find a set of solutions that meet the requirements?

*The reference answer is* $Q=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{array}\right)$, $A=Q\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & & \\
& 1 & \\
& & 0
\end{array}\right) Q^{T}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Your reference answer doesn't satisfy `Transpose[Q] . A . Q == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Note that the reference answer is $Q.A.Q^{T}$. if $Q=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{array}\right)^{T}$, the answer is still correct

Comment: I agree, my fault. But right Q as given in your question without transposition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NMinimize` evaluates quite fast:

```
mini = NMinimize[{#.# &[Flatten[Transpose[Q].A.Q - {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} ]] + 10^10 #.# &[ Flatten[IdentityMatrix[3] - Transpose[Q].Q]  ]}, 
Join[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, Flatten[A]], WorkingPrecision -> 15]


 Transpose[Q].A.Q - {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} /. mini[[2]]
 (*{{0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-15}, {0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-15,0.*10^-15}, {0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-15}}*)
```

The result for matrix `A` matches the reference answer

```
 A /. mini[[2]] // Chop // Rationalize
 (* {{1/2, 0, -(1/2)}, {0, 1, 0}, {-(1/2), 0, 1/2}} *)
```

but `Q` doesn't match the reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope to find a set of exact solutions rather than numerical solutions quickly.

Comment: @Montevideo Ok you could try `Minimize`? Thereby you should add a constraint `Q^T.Q==Identity[3]`

Comment: After I added the constraint `Q^T.Q==IdentityMatrix[3]`, it still runs without returning results.

Comment: @Montevidoe I modified my answer. `Minimize` version doesn't evaluate...

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228412/why-does-specifying-the-solution-domain-seriously-affect-the-solution-speed), but I have found new problems.

Comment: @Montevideo What a simple trick. `Solve` instead of `FindInstance` fgives 8 solutions quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the rigorous proof of the following to the interested reader:

```
v = {Sqrt[1/2], 0, Sqrt[1/2]};
qq = Transpose[Simplify[TrigExpand[Append[RotationMatrix[2 ArcTan[u]].
                                          (Normalize /@ NullSpace[{#}]), #] &[v]]]]
   {{(-1 + u^2)/(Sqrt[2] (1 + u^2)), -((Sqrt[2] u)/(1 + u^2)), 1/Sqrt[2]},
    {-((2 u)/(1 + u^2)), (1 - u^2)/(1 + u^2), 0},
    {-((-1 + u^2)/(Sqrt[2] (1 + u^2))), (Sqrt[2] u)/(1 + u^2), 1/Sqrt[2]}}

aa = FullSimplify[qq.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.Transpose[qq]]
   {{1/2, 0, -1/2}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1/2, 0, 1/2}}
```

Comment: This answer is great, but I don’t yet know its mathematical principles.