# How to find some matrices that satisfy the constraints

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I know that the three eigenvalues of the real third order matrix `A`  are `-1`, `1`, `1`, and the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue `-1` is $(0,1,1)^T$. I want to find a matrix `A` that meets the requirements.

```
A = Array[x, {3, 3}];
FindInstance[(Eigenvalues[A] == {-1, 1, 
     1}) && (A.{{0, 1, 1}}\[Transpose] == -1*{{0, 1, 1}}\[Transpose]) , Flatten[A], Reals]
```

But the above code returns an empty set. What can I do to find some matrices that meet the constraints?

Comment: This is effectively a dupe of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228375), and the solutions in there apply here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want

First we try to narrow down the search space a little

```
A = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
A.{0, 1, 1} == -1 * {0, 1, 1}
```

returns

```
{b + c, e + f, h + i} == {0, -1, -1}
```

then

```
sol = FindInstance[Eigenvalues[{{a, b, -b}, {d, e, -1 - e}, {g, h, -1 - h}}] ==
                               {-1, 1, 1}, {a, b, d, e, g, h}, Integers]
```

returns

```
{{a -> 0, b -> -1, d -> 0, e -> 0, g -> -1, h -> -2}}
```

Note: Changing that `Integers` to `Reals` and adding the number of desired solutions will let `FindInstance` give you more matrices if that is what you need.

and

```
mat = {{a, b, -b}, {d, e, -1 - e}, {g, h, -1 - h}} /. sol
```

returns

```
{{{0, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}, {-1, -2, 1}}}
```

and

```
Eigensystem[mat]
```

returns

```
{{-1, 1, 1}, {{0, 1, 1}, {2, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}
```

which seems to satisfy your conditions.

Please check all this very carefully.

Comment: The last solution found by Bill is special, in that this is exactly the nondiagonalizable solution.